# Comparing int value with null returns zero records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
Declare @value int
Select 21 where 1 <> @value
```

And I get 0 results.

How can this be justified. 1 cannot be equal to null!!!

Comment: You mean `Select 21 where 1 is not null`

Comment: To make this sound as zen as possible. One can not compare a value to a value that is not known.

Comment: To expand, `NULL` is a state not a value.  If you don't know someone's name, what would you say when asked where they should be in an alphabetical list?

Comment: ...or when asked if their name is *not* "Bob"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand are you telling me SQLServer can't make assumptions like "I can't remember that guys name but I'm pretty sure it's not Bob"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL must be handled in the following manner,

Equals null:

```
Column IS NULL
```

Not Equal null:

```
Column IS NOT NULL
```

Or:

```
ISNULL(Column,-1) = -1  
ISNULL(Column,-1) <> -1
```

Comment: Setting a coulmn value to be -1 if it's NULL and then comparing to -1 will create unpredicted behaviour if the true value of the column is -1.
The first part of this answer is correct but the second part is not recommended.

Comment: yes, i would never use that if there were indeed -1 values possible.  it was purely an example of how to handle NULLS with a NON NULL compare

Comment: One thing working with data in databases has taught me it's that you should never rely on the data to be how you expect it. Expect it to be completely wrong and code defensively to that standard covering each possibility and the end result will be a far more robust solution less prone to errors and behaviour based on bad data from an error in the code earlier along in the application.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a markup for unknown, it is not a value - meaning it can be anything including 1, so your query returns 0 record. Following query will return a record instead.

```
select 21 where 1 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take into consideration ANSI_NULLs, based on how this is set you will get different results.

When ANSI_NULLS is set to ON

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

IF (NULL=NULL)
    PRINT 'EQUAL'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT EQUAL'
GO
```

Result : NOT EQUAL

When ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF (NULL = NULL (; )

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

IF (NULL=NULL)
    PRINT 'EQUAL'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT EQUAL'
GO
```

Result : EQUAL